# What does the class "Code" represent in memwatch's diff report?

Tags: node.js, node-memwatch

I'm tracking down a memory leak in my nodejs app, and using memwatch for that. The diff reports shows me that 2 classes are growing, one is "Array", the other is "Code". For example:

```
{
    what: "Code",
    size_bytes: 41440,
    size: "40.47 kb",
    +: 167,
    -: 75
}
```

There's no class "Code" in my app, nor can I see any in the immediate libraries I am using. Does the class "Code" have a spacial meaning in memwatch? And how can I troubleshoot further from here?